# AndroidPlot: How can I skip some of the required range values of a fixed boundary domain

Tags: androidplot

I'm using Androidplot for my charts.

I would like to know if it is possible - and in that case how - I could accomplish the below.

I set a fixed boundary domain as per below to represent the hours of the day:
p.setDomainBoundaries(0, 23, BoundaryMode.FIXED);

And I would like to represent some quantity count on the y-axis to correspond to the time of the day.

I could use a simpleXYSeries as given in the example: 
https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/master/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/TimeSeriesActivity.java?at=master

However, the one challenge I would like to overcome is the capability of skipping some of hours where corresponding records are missing, and be able to leave those unplotted. One solution I thought-of was to create the series from an arrayList replacing all the missing values by zeros however the resulting plot isn't pretty.

I would appreciate guidance on how I could do this with androidplot or any other way that could be suggested.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to accomplish what I was looking for:
new SimpleXYSeries(nums, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED,"Title")

creating a SimpleXYSeries with ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED allowed me to specify a domain value and its corresponding range with. 
Even when two series - plotted in the same graph- mismatch in the domain values the plots still are drawn perfectly as I required.

Thanks.